# Merge more than 2 branches/heads at once in Git?

Tags: git, merge

The question is straightforward: I have three heads (branches in this case), and I want to merge them into master (one of them being master). Let's call these `master`, `foo` and `bar`. I know I could do two merges separately, but I've heard it can be done once and I want to try.

Comment: That sounds like the [octopus merge strategy](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge foo bar
```

That will merge the two branches into master...this works for any number of branches - only if **there are not merge confilcts** in this "octopus merge"
The git log --graph will look something like this.

```
|    
*-.  
|\ \ 
| | |
| | |
```

Comment: So does it first merge `foo` into `master` and then `bar` into that? How does the `git log --graph` look? (I'm on mobile so can't test)